# No wysiwyg filter present in text format

Tags: wysiwyg

I keep reading you select the wysiwyg filter in configuration->content authoring-> text formats but it doesn't exist for me.

How can I get that filter to appear in list?

I have the wysiwyg module correctly installed and enabled.

Comment: which editor are you using with WYSIWYG module?

Comment: I am using Tinymce editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to do the following:

- first add new text format from `admin/config/content/formats`
- then check the correct options for your new custom text format
- now go to wysiwyg configuration page `admin/config/content/wysiwyg`
- you should see your new custom text format along with dropdown list to choose TinyMCE editor
- make sure to select TinyMCE editor and click save

Note: in order for you to see/select different text format you need to have more than one text format (other than Plain text)

Comment: Actually, I had high hopes this would work but having done it I am still getting no changes to text in output.

Comment: so you can't see/select text format?

Comment: I can see my text formats and I can select tinymce for each but I cannot choose wysiwyg for the filter even though I can configure wysiwyg profiles and now followed a stanford tutorial but still text buttons are not working.

Comment: The problem the path I'm setting is wrong for css define and not sure where to get help with this in here.

Comment: I'm confused here, so css define is related to text buttons?

Comment: I am sorry to have been so unclear so have set up a new question because I think your answer is good considering my initial question. So I will leave this particular one as is and follow my next question.